# Как настроить переключение полей с помощью tab? Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Первый раз разбираюсь в winforms, как прописать поведение при переключении tab-ом? Т.к. сбивается цвет при вводе под выделением таба, под кликом все норм. А еще по умолчанию первое поле username при запуске выделяется, как исправить? Пробовал просто прописать поведение при нажатии на таб, но не катит.
Повторюсь, первый раз тут работаю, возможно решение прям перед носом, но я не нашел. Спасибо.
[image: Первое поле при запуске выделяется, как исправить?]

[image: Первое вводится под кликом, а остальные 2 поля под табом]

Comment: Цвета используются системные или вручную заданы? Если вручную, то _все_ или часть?

Comment: То, что первое поле выделяется - это хорошо и правильно. Сразу понятно, куда вводить. Плохо, когда фокус неизвестно где: приходится снимать руку с клавы на мышу и кликать в поле.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Сначала в дизайнере прописан белый цвет полей, но при клике на 1 из 3 полей и вводе каких либо данных цвет меняется на другой и этот цвет уже задается вручную

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov т.е. первый скриншот - это хорошо?

Comment: То, что фокус устанавливается на поле ввода - это хорошо. То, что содержимое поля выбрано (select) - тоже нормально: если оно правильное - жмём Tab - переходим к другому полю; если неправильно - сразу начинаем вводить нужное, затирая прежнее.

Comment: Вас не устраивает цвет выделения?

Comment: У контролов WinForms есть свойства `TabIndex` и `TabStop` - задайте их для правильного порядка и для пропуска ненужных.

Comment: Проблема в том, что все предустановки из-за переключения табом стираются. Например, убирается шифрование пароля звездочками, предустановленный цвет введенных данных стирается, при клике на одно поле и последущее переключение табом создает абсолютно пустое поле. Т.е. коряво все работает.
Про Табиндекс и стоп я знаю, но оно не поможет) Мне бы прописать какие-то действия при нажатии таб... Можно так? Что-бы параллельно переключалось на новое поле и присваивались предустановки?

Comment: Не видя ваш код, невозможно сказать, почему такое поведение. Возможно, дело в привязке данных. Возможно, дело в имеющихся обработчиках событий: получения фокуса, активации, выбора.

Comment: Прошу прощения, пойду потыкаю, может все же разберусь

Comment: Раз у вас что-то происходит само (данные изменяются и т. п,), то наверняка прописаны какие-то события. См. например [эти](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: Нет, использовалось не само, а наоборот предписания не выполнялись, я уже разобрался, фокус прописал и все пошло. Благодарю и прошу прощения)